# Copy constructor with reference counting

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I am trying to implement reference counting. Every copy of object should increment the counter for it. 
My code looks

```
class Person{
public:
    struct Kids{
        Kids(){
            count = 2;
            boy = "Alex";
            girl= " Lisa";
        }
        int count;
        string boy;
        string girl;
    };

    Person( string name , int age){
        this -> name = name;
        this -> age  = age;
    }
    Person( const Person& a){
        one = a.one;
        one -> count++;
        age = a.age;
        name = a.name;
        for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            family[i] = a.family[i];
        }
    };
    void PrintIt(){
        cout << one -> count << endl;
    }
private:
    Kids *one;
    string name;
    int    age;
    Kids family[5];

};

int main(){
    Person one("Jogn",50);
    //return 0;
    Person two(one);
    two.PrintIt();
}
```

And it throws seg fault. I have tried to pass object to copy constructor as a pointer , which resulted in the same output. How can create a copy constructor ,that will point to object via pointers , which will result in possible reference counting?

Comment: You are not initializing Kids *one anywhere. so its null pointer derefence on line `one -> count++`. you probably need in the name,age constructor `one = new Kids();` Also, your implementation can be a litlte bit complicated, why not just use the std::shared_ptr to do that for you?

Comment: @AleksanderFular, to be correct, it's not `nullptr`, it may point anywhere, but anyway it's UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Kids *one;
```

Seems to be uninitialized. When you copy a value to it. this value is also unitialized, since it is private, and i don't see any init code for it. You have to add something like

```
kids(new Kids())
```

in Person constructor which is not copy one.

ps. don't forget operator= and destructor.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `std::shared_ptr`, it is available in C++ 11. This template class has the advantages of being well tested and already developed. Here you have a [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) to the documentation.

Comment: Pretty sure they are not trying to model Person's and kids for a really world application and that this is more of a hobby/learning project to gain a deeper understanding of reference counting

Answer (score 0):

just make a static variable in private and outside your class initialize it to zero using the scope resolution operator. Then inside your constructor increment it by one. Each time you will make an object its constructor will be called and the static variable will be incremented by one. Then when ever you want you can display that variable where ever you want (again by using scope resolution operator).